# Is it possible for try-with-resource to fail to close resources?

Tags: java

As per Oracle documentation

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one or more resources. A resource is as an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource

If a resource does not implement AutoCloseable it cannot be declared within try block, it has to be declared in the body part & has to be explicitly closed in finally block.
Is it possible for try-with-resource to fail to clean up resources unless you use the idiom incorrectly like if there are nested resources & close() call is not idempotent for the underlying resource?
What I understand is try-with-resource only ensures close() getting called behind the scene, but if close itself does not close underlying resources try-with-resource will remain ineffective to clean-up resources.
Does anyone have a contrary view or more clarification?

Comment: Can you produce code for a case where you think there might be a failure?

Comment: This probably comes down to "when will a finally block not be run" (which is very rare, basically just situations like System.exit where it should not matter anyway)?

Comment: Also note that all try-with-resources does is call the `close` method. If that method properly does its job or not is another question.

Comment: I cannot produce a code right now, I did not face this in my daily coding, but was asked by somebody in a interview & I told try-with-resource will always succeed, and interviewer was not convinced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding code that does not actually work (like your example of `close()` methods not actually closing the resource) or such completely external factors as people attaching debuggers to side-step cleanup, I can think of three situations in which try-with-resources might fail to clean up a resource:

- Power failure, hardware failure, OS crash or VM crash. There isn't much any software can do about such things, so they are outside the scope of resource handling. However, you still need to keep it in mind in case you're thinking about managing such things as mandatory locking files and whatnot with a try-with-resources statement.
- Asynchronous exceptions, such as those generated by `Thread.stop()`. If a thread is "stopped" in this way while in the clean-up code, then the clean-up code will be aborted. The unsafety of such asynchronous exceptions is why `Thread.stop()` is [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) and replaced with `Thread.interrupt()`, which is safe.
- If `System.exit()` is called. This might be considered as any of the above cases, except that it might happen under "normal circumstances".

In all other respects, you should be able to rest assured that `close()` will be called. Try-with-several-resources is the same as nested try blocks, so clean-up code throwing exceptions won't stop other clean-up routines.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault()) {
    return fs.getPath(aStringVar);
}
```

If `FileSystems.getDefault()` returns a `sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem`, as it did for me on a RedHat machine with Java 8 SE, it'll throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` while closing. Despite IntelliJ displaying warnings and telling you to wrap that in a try-with-resources, you should not, unless you want to deal with that stupid exception.